# Definir diferentes Initial View Controller Swift

Tags: swift2, swift, xcode

Estoy haciendo una app en `IOS`, en la que compruebo si un usuario ya esta registrado o no.

Si está registrado, le muestro una pantalla, pero si no esta registrado le muestro otra.

Como puedo hacer para mostrar una pantalla u otra si ya tengo definido un `Initial View Controller` en el `StoryBoard`??

Aqui mi código:

```
if comprobarUsuario(datos) {
   //Existe el usuario, por lo que se va directamente a la app
}
else {
   //No existe el usuario, por lo que se muestra el formulario
}
```

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado esta [fantástica respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14926009/1468942) que te será de ayuda y [ésta otra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27343365/1468942) que es específica de swift.

Los pasos a seguir son:

1. Pon un StoryBoard ID en las 2 posibles pantallas iniciales.
2. Des del StoryBoard no selecciones ningún StoryBoard cómo inicial y si ya lo tienes seleccionado, desmárcalo.

En este punto, comprueba que si lanzas la aplicación te aparece el warning:

> Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'MainStoryboard' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?

Y la pantalla inicial es `nil`.

Si esto no es así es que te has olvidado de desmarcar el StoryBoard inicial.
Si todo bien hasta aquí continuamos:

3. Ve a las preferencias de la aplicación y:

   3.1 preferencias --> target --> Info. Ahí elimina el valor de la variable `Main storyboard file base name`.

   3.2 En el tab `General` elimina el valor de `Main Interface` (esto elimina el warning de arriba).

Ahora diferenciamos el punto 4 (sin `swift`) y el punto 5 (con `swift`)

4. [SIN SWIFT] En `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` ya puedes crear el window inicial:

   ```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
   {
       self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];

       UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

       UIViewController *viewController = // determine the initial view controller here and instantiate it with [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:<storyboard id>];

       self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
       [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

       return YES;
   }
   ```
5. [CON SWIFT]

   ```
   func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

       self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
       let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
       var exampleViewController: ExampleViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ExampleController") as! ExampleViewController

       self.window?.rootViewController = exampleViewController

       self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

       return true
   }
   ```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Funciona perfecto