# Definir diferentes pantallas de inicio Android

Tags: java, android

Esta pregunta ya la realicé para [`swift`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/15469/definir-diferentes-initial-view-controller-swift)

Estoy haciendo una app en `Android`, en la que compruebo si un usuario ya está registrado o no.

Si está registrado, le muestro una pantalla, pero si no está registrado le muestro otra.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para mostrar una pantalla u otra?

Aqui mi código:

```
if (comprobarUsuario(String datos)) {
   //Existe el usuario, por lo que se va directamente a la app
}
else {
   //No existe el usuario, por lo que se muestra el formulario
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si son **Activity** tus pantallas simplemente  realiza el intent para abrirlas:

```
    Intent intent;
    if (comprobarUsuario(String datos)) {
        //Existe el usuario, por lo que se va directamente a la app
        intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    }else {
        //No existe el usuario, por lo que se muestra el formulario
        intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    }
    //Inicia la Activity.
    startActivity(intent);
```

Si las "pantallas" fueran **Fragments** se realizaría mediante una transacción reemplazando el fragmento:

```
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    if (comprobarUsuario(String datos)) {
        //Existe el usuario, por lo que se va directamente a la app
        Fragment fragment = new FragmentMain();
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction =
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }   else {
        //No existe el usuario, por lo que se muestra el formulario
        Fragment fragment = new FragmentLogin();
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction =
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Crea dos `Activity`s y lanzalas segun lo que necesites:

```
Intent intent = null;

if (comprobarUsuario(String datos)) {
    intent = new Intent(this, AplicacionActivity.class);
} else {
    intent = new Intent(this, RegistrarUsuarioActivity.class);
}
startActivity(intent);
```